# Multiple arguments for a Callback function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, arguments, matlab-guide

I created my first GUI using GUIDE in MATLAB.

The aim of the GUI is to execute a function with different arguments

The basic structure of the code is the following :

I have several arguments that the user will choose and then execute a function with all these arguments. The function called, named RSM is stored in the same folder as the GUI .fig and .m file

The GUI basic structure looks like this

- different Listbox where the user can choose different values. Each listbox is one argument for my main function
- A push button to execute the main function with the arguments

Each listbox is coded like this:

```
function popupmenu_contour_style_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
contour_style=get(hObject,'Value');
handles.contour_style=contour_style;
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

then the main push button is coded like this:

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

fitted_values = RSM_plot_function(...
    handles.fullpathname,...
    get(handles.checkbox_realspace,'Value'),...
    get(handles.checkbox_reciprocalspace,'Value'),...
    get(handles.popupmenu_plot_type,'Value'),...
    get(handles.checkbox_color,'Value'),...
    get(handles.checkbox_correctionforomega,'Value'),...
    get(handles.checkbox_includeoriginline,'Value'),...
    get(handles.popupmenu_contour_style,'Value'),...
    get(handles.listbox_fitting,'Value'),...
    get(handles.grid_density,'Value'),...
    get(handles.contour_number,'Value')...
    );
```

I used this technique to read the values of each listbox even if the user does not change them.

When I run the program for the first time it works perfectly. However, if I change the parameters of some listboxes I got a strange error:

```
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Error using handle.handle/get
Invalid or deleted object.

Error in RSM>pushbutton2_Callback (line 227)
fitted_values = RSM_plot_function(...
```

I am not sure to understand the reason of this error. Neither am I sure that I used the correct method to get the values of the listboxes and pass them as arguments to my RSM function.

Comment: did you run the file or the from GUIDE directly?

Comment: Hi, I run the program by the file. Both produces the same result anyway.